# C++ memory allocation from C

Tags: c++

How do you allocate memory in C++ with this C code:

```
airline* myairline = ( airline *) malloc(sizeof( airline));
```

Is it:

`airline* myairline = new myairline`?

If so, why don't we need to specify the size?

Comment: you don't. Do you need to use C++ inside C code?

Comment: it is specified, its size is 1, 1*sizeof( airline)

Comment: The compiler knows how big it is, (and how to call its ctor).

Comment: but what i mean is how to convert the c code into c++ but with the sizeof(airline) not 1.

Comment: It's more like `airline myairline;`.

Comment: @user2557607 You payin' attention to the comments? Martin James wrote: "The compiler knows how big it is, (and how to call its ctor)."

Comment: `airline myairline;` is totally different; that gets allocated on the stack, not the heap.

Comment: @crimson_penguin, Yes, and all that was asked in the question was how to allocate memory. Allocating on the stack is less typing and less problematic. If dynamic memory allocation is required, there are smart pointers available.

Comment: Sure, unless there's a reason, you should use the stack. But the difference should definitely be noted. And the question was also asking how to do what the C code is doing, but in C++.

Comment: One wonder what 'airline' actually is. struct, class or something else?

Comment: @ExpatEgghead That shouldn't matter. If if does, there's something terribly wrong!

Answer (score 2):

`C` and `C++` code, particularly memory management functions, should not get mixed!

By calling `( airline *) malloc(sizeof( airline));` you are actually making a big mistake.

To allocate memory in `C++` use new keyword. It ensures proper initialization of all member fields, runs the appropriate constructors, initialzier lists, in other words, does all the things that should be done for an object.

If you `malloc` memory for an object there's a good chance it will actually be unusable.

Comment: so all i have to do is airline* myairline = new myairline?

Comment: @user2557607, `airline myairline;` is safer and less typing. `new` is a liabiltiy.

Comment: airline* myairline you mean?

Comment: @user2557607, No, pointers are just extra work unless you really have a good reason to have one. That will leave you with an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: If you use "new" don't forget to "delete"(!!!) to prevent memory leakage.

If you absolutely sure you need to place "myairline" on the heap, I would use a smart-pointer that will auto-delete the object.

You should also notice what "Chris" wrote, it is usually safer to create the object on the stack ("airline myairline;"), but notice that it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the size. Operator new allocates enough memory for holding an object of airline type, constructs the object and gives you a pointer to it.

Opeeator delete doesn't need the size either.

Comment: how about this? how do you using new keyword for this code             p->plast = (char *) malloc( strlen( pl )+1 );

Comment: @user2557607, Easier to make it a `std::string`.

Comment: If you are learning c++ try not to learn it the c way, you are in a dvantage if you can directly think in c++ :) so yes, use std library, a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to use a 'new' statement to allocate dynamic memory in c++ because 'new' statement raises an exception in case of an error. And the size of the allocated memory is going to be the exact size of the airline object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to use `new`, extremely rarely in C++14. We have RAII, so use it.

Comment: So all I have to do is only airline* myairline = new my airline ? Thank you

Comment: @user2557607 `TheClass anObj;`

Comment: @chris I agree with you completely on it being rarely if ever necessary to use `new` in C++, but I'm curious why you say that C++14 makes it even *less* necessary. What new features of the proposed C++14 (or, what limitations of the older C++ standards) have affected this?

Comment: @CodyGray, Instead of either using `new` to initialize a `std::unique_ptr` or rolling your own `make_unique`, there's going to be a `std::make_unique`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the new operator , it automatically calculate the size, so you don not need to calculate it yourself.